# Typescript not parsing JSX inside forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I'm working with React and Next.js in Typescript and I'm trying to make this wrapper component that will bundle together a Next.js `<Link />` component and a `<a />` tag:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import Link, { LinkProps } from 'next/link';

type EnhancedLinkProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode[];
} & LinkProps;

const EnhancedLink = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, EnhancedLinkProps>(({
  as,
  passHref,
  prefetch,
  replace,
  shallow,
  scroll,
  href,
  children,
  ...rest
}, ref) => (
  <Link
    href={href}
    as={as}
    passHref={passHref}
    prefetch={prefetch}
    replace={replace}
    shallow={shallow}
    scroll={scroll}
    href={href}
  >
    <a {...rest} ref={ref}>
      {children}
    </a>
  </Link>
))

export default EnhancedLink;
```

Problem is that I want to support forwarding refs, but as soon as I wrap my function in forwardRef typescript fails to parse my JSX. I get this error message on the line with `<Link...`:

```
"'Link' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Link'?ts(2749)"
```

Seems like it is maybe registering the `<>` around Link as Typescript syntax.

I used this example to set up my forwardRef as typescript code:

```
type Props = { children: React.ReactNode; type: "submit" | "button" };
export type Ref = HTMLButtonElement;
export const FancyButton = React.forwardRef<Ref, Props>((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="MyClassName" type={props.type}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

Taken from [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forward_and_create_ref). I was assuming that the example should be good, but when I copy paste that directly into my code, I also get an error on the line where the JSX starts (i.e. `<button>...`):

```
"Cannot find name 'button'.ts(2304)"
```

Button is just a good old HTML element, so it's definitely not picking up the JSX here either.

I tried rewriting the arrow function with a explicit return statement. From:

```
() => (<button />)
```

To:

```
() => { return (<button />) }
```

Did not work either, same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing something very obvious :)

The filename just had to be renamed from `.ts` to `.tsx`.

Comment: Oh shoot so sorry, happened to me as well trying to make a context provider in a `.ts` file 